# Google Earth Engine Landsat NDVI

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, ndvi, landsat, landsat-8

I'm trying to map deforestation using Landsat NDVI time-series. But unfortunately I can't find the data from 2022 - 2023, on the other side data before that year is available. Can someone explain me what happened to the data? Here's my code, I only change the filter date to get yearly NDVI data. My AOI located in Jambi, Indonesia

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_8DAY_NDVI')
                  .filterDate('2022-01-01', '2022-12-31');
var colorized = dataset.select('NDVI');
print(colorized)
var ndvi=colorized.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
print(ndvi)

var ndvi_crop=ndvi.clip(table);

var colorizedVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};
Map.addLayer(ndvi_crop, colorizedVis, 'Colorized');

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ndvi_crop,
  description: 'avg_NDVI_2021',
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13, 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Landsat Collection 1 is deprecated and isn't being updated anymore (as far as I can recall). It seems like you have to wait a bit for your NDVI imagery based on Collection 2. See [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/landsat):

> Notice: Landsat Collection 1 (and Pre-Collection) datasets will be
> removed from the Earth Engine Data Catalog starting in the second half
> of 2024, and computed datasets like 32-day NDVI will be generated from
> Collection 2. Use the migration guide to update your Earth Engine
> scripts, modules, and apps to Collection 2 by July 1, 2024 to avoid
> failed requests. See the Medium post "Farewell to Landsat Collection
> 1" for more information.